# Bing Maps convert from Pixel position to Latitude Longitude

Tags: javascript, coordinates, bing-maps, bing-api

So here is the deal, I want to have a Pin always on the left top corner of the map. So I thought everytime that I "travel" through the map to get the cords of the TopLeft corner and drag the pin around.
Using the following reference I created the maths. However it doesnt seem to work.

[MSDN Bing Map Scale Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx)

As the code suggests I have a fixed lat and lon so if I generated first the pixelX,Y and then try to get the lat lon again I would know its a success! however this is the console output.

x:520755.97951431107, y:3.820808909668405

150,54.56342799999999

This is the html of the map element : `<div id="BingMap" class="map"></div>`
And there are other elements around it.
Any ideas as to why its wrong?
Thank you!.

```
var latitude = 54.563428;
var longitude = -1.212623;
var sinLatitude = Math.sin(latitude * Math.PI / 180);
var pixelX = ((longitude + 180) / 360) * 256 * Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
var pixelY = (0.5 - Math.log((1 + sinLatitude) / (1 - sinLatitude)) / (4 * Math.PI)) * map.getZoom();
console.log("x:" + pixelX + ", y:" + pixelY);

var mapSize = map.getZoom();
var x = (Clip(pixelX, 0, mapSize - 1) / mapSize) - 0.5;
var y = 0.5 - (Clip(pixelY, 0, mapSize - 1) / mapSize);

mainPushPinDockLatitude = 90 - 360 * Math.atan(Math.exp(-y * 2 * Math.PI)) / Math.PI;
mainPushPinDockLongitude = 360 * x;

console.log(mainPushPinDockLongitude + "," + mainPushPinDockLatitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always want a pushpin in the top left corner of the map why not overlay it on top of the map as a standard HTML image. This will save you the trouble of having to do any tile math. For example:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<div id="MyMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
<img src="mypin.png" style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:10px;></div>
```